# style responsive nav menu

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am trying to style my responsive nav drop-down menu and change the background color but can't seem to figure it out.  I would like the items in the list below to have a gray background of #cccccc.

the full site is located here:
http://adanburlington.com/giotto2/index.html

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav hidden">
<li><a href="#" onclick="navFire()">Fire Alarm Systems</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="navSecurity()">Security & Intrusion</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="navTV()">Closed Circuit TV</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="navAccess()">Access Control</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="navInt()">Systems Integration</a></li>
</ul>
```

Responsive CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width : 1100px){
ul.nav
{ position: static;
  display: none;}

li.nav {margin-bottom: 1px;}

ul.nav li, li.nav a {width: 100%;}

.show-menu {display:block;}

li.nav > ul.hidden { 
display: block !important;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where you are trying to set it in the CSS you listed in your question.

I would think

```
ul.nav.hidden li a {
     background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

would do it if you don't have another statement for this that counteracts it.  If you do, add another class to the ul so you can make your selector specific to this instance.

If your li has padding, either drop the "a" off the selector or add "ul.nav.hidden li" as a second selector.

Btw, you have "li.nav" a few places.  For this section of html, at least, your lis don't have the class "nav" but are instead inside an element with class "nav", so it should be ".nav li" if you are trying to target those. ;-)

Comment: That did it....thanks!  Sorry, should have mentioned that before I tried ul.nav.hidden li and forgot the "a".....thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
ul li {
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
```